# Google PageSpeed Insights - 1 external CSS file blocking

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo

I'm trying to optimize a website with Google PageSpeed Insight Tool..

There is one point I just can't figure out how to fix

1 external CSS file is blocking

Have tried everything.. Moved the `<link>` down in the bottom with all `<script>` tags.. Have also tried with an asynchronosly load with https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/master/loadCSS.js

All solutions ends up with more "errors"

Here is the page insight

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.dynaccount.com

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery . I'd focus on: using a CDN, and concatenating and minifying files.

Comment: Is CDN or another subdomain a solution to the "issue" with blocking js/css files? :)

Comment: No, the link i referenced was the 'solution'. This question has been asked before plenty of times. http://bit.ly/1sithqB & http://bit.ly/1sitzO4

Answer (score 0):

The issue there is that all CSS files are blocking, in so much that the page can not be rendered until said files have been downloaded.

The Google Pagespeed tools suggest that you inline all of the "Above the fold" CSS, as when CSS is inlined, it's not a blocker to the page load.

Addy Osmani [produced a video](http://addyosmani.com/blog/detecting-critical-above-the-fold-css-with-paul-kinlan-video/) explaining this and showing you how to extract the "Above the fold" css.